# How to use ButterKnife inside adapter

Tags: android, listview, bind, android-adapter, butterknife

I would like to use ButterKnife to bind my views inside listView adpater.

I tried this, but i can not simply use my "spinner" var.

```
public class WarmSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Warm> {

    Context context;

    public WarmSpinnerAdapter(Context context, int resource, Warm[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_spinner, null);


        return v;
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.spinner)
    public void onClick() {
        //open dialog and select
    }

    static class ViewHolder {

        @BindView(R.id.spinner)
        MyTextView spinner;

        ViewHolder(View view) {
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: `@OnClick` should be in `ViewHolder`

Answer (score 19):

You should pass your view to ButterKnife to bind it first.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_spinner, null);
    ButterKnife.bind(this,v);

    return v;
}
```

Then you will have access to your Views.

Answer (score 3):

ButterKnife is binding your view to the `ViewHolder` class, so `WarmSpinnerAdapter` won't be able to access it directly. Instead, you should move this part inside the `ViewHolder` class:

```
@OnClick(R.id.spinner)
public void onClick() {
    //open dialog and select
}
```

From there, you could either call an internal method from the adapter or execute the logic directly inside the `ViewHolder`

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using an ArrayAdapter you need to have the proper ViewHolder logic in your `getView()` method. (You're onClick annotation is also not set correctly as it should be placed inside the ViewHolder class.)

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_spinner, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // now you can access your spinner var.
    MyTextView spinner = viewHolder.spinner;

    return convertView;
}
```