# Attach Adapter to ListView using Butterknife

Tags: android, listview, butterknife

I am using ButterKnife for my android project. I am able to bind all my views in fragment using Butterknife, but unable to setAdapter to my ListView using Butterknife. Though I can bind it up simply using 
`ListView.setAdapter(m_adapter)` but I want to do it using Butterknife only.

Any help ?

Note: I am not asking for binding views inside Adapter using Butterknife. What I am asking for is: How to set Adapter with ListView using Butterknife.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya: I am not asking for binding views inside Adapter. I am explicitly asking for **binding Adapter with ListView using ButterKnife**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use ButterKnife inside adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40890185/how-to-use-butterknife-inside-adapter)

Comment: you can't set adapter using butter-knife. Butterknife only use for bind View and ViewGroup.

Comment: What you are asking is `Data Binding`.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass your view to ButterKnife and bind it

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_spinner, null);
ButterKnife.bind(this,v);
return v;
}
```